# Why is Enlightenment 17 (Debian 8) not showing an icon when plugging a CD or USB pin drive?

Tags: desktop

I installed the default E17 with aptitude. E17 doesn't show any icons on the Desktop when I'm inserting a CD or an pin drive.  Did I miss any switch in the Enlightenment settings?